# C++\IronPython integration example code?

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio, visual-c++, ironpython

I'm looking for a **simple** example code for **C++\IronPython integration**, i.e. embedding python code inside a C++, or better yet, Visual C++ program.

The example code should include: how to share objects between the languages, how to call functions\methods back and forth etc...

Also, an explicit setup procedure would help too. (How to include the Python runtime dll in Visual Studio etc...)

I've found a nice example for C#\IronPython [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ironpython.aspx), but couldn't find C++\IronPython example code.

Comment: Not a full answer but you probably either want to COM interop.  Define an identical interface both in your C++ code and in a C# class library.  Have that interface be a thin wrapper around what you need with regard to scopes, engines, executing code, and the ObjectOperations class.  You'll need to do lifetime management of the objects on the C++ side of course.  You can either host the CLR or register the .NET assembly as a COM object directly.  Then you just CoCreate it from the C++ side and now you can talk to IronPython.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE - I've written a more generic example (plus a link to a zip file containing the entire VS2008 project) as entry on my blog [here.](http://oldschooldotnet.blogspot.com/2011/04/scripting-ccli-with-ironpython-visual.html)

Sorry, I am so late to the game, but here is how I have integrated IronPython into a C++/cli app in Visual Studio 2008 - .net 3.5. (actually mixed mode app with C/C++)

I write add-ons for a map making applicaiton written in Assembly.  The API is exposed so that C/C++ add-ons can be written. I mix C/C++ with C++/cli.  Some of the elements from this example are from the API (such as XPCALL and CmdEnd() - please just ignore them)

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void XPCALL PythonCmd2(int Result, int Result1, int Result2) 
{
  if(Result==X_OK)
  {
        try
        {
              String^ filename = gcnew String(txtFileName);
              String^ path = Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->Location;
              ScriptEngine^ engine = Python::CreateEngine();
              ScriptScope^ scope = engine->CreateScope();
              ScriptSource^ source = engine->CreateScriptSourceFromFile(String::Concat(Path::GetDirectoryName(path), "\\scripts\\", filename + ".py"));

              scope->SetVariable("DrawingList", DynamicHelpers::GetPythonTypeFromType(AddIn::DrawingList::typeid));
              scope->SetVariable("DrawingElement", DynamicHelpers::GetPythonTypeFromType(AddIn::DrawingElement::typeid));
              scope->SetVariable("DrawingPath", DynamicHelpers::GetPythonTypeFromType(AddIn::DrawingPath::typeid));
              scope->SetVariable("Node", DynamicHelpers::GetPythonTypeFromType(AddIn::Node::typeid));

              source->Execute(scope);
        }
        catch(Exception ^e)
        {
              Console::WriteLine(e->ToString());
              CmdEnd();
        }
  }
  else
  {
        CmdEnd();
  }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

As you can see, I expose to IronPython some objects (DrawingList, DrawingElement, DrawingPath & Node).  These objects are C++/cli objects that I created to expose "things" to IronPython.

When the C++/cli source->Execute(scope) line is called, the only python line
to run is the DrawingList.RequestData.

RequestData takes a delegate and a data type.

When the C++/cli code is done, it calls the delegate pointing to the
function "diamond"

In the function diamond it retrieves the requested data with the call to
DrawingList.RequestedValue() The call to DrawingList.AddElement(dp) adds the
new element to the Applications visual Database.

And lastly the call to DrawingList.EndCommand() tells the FastCAD engine to
clean up and end the running of the plugin.

```
import clr
def diamond(Result1, Result2, Result3):

  if(Result1 == 0):

    dp = DrawingPath()
    dp.drawingStuff.EntityColor = 2
    dp.drawingStuff.SecondEntityColor = 2

    n = DrawingList.RequestedValue()

    dp.Nodes.Add(Node(n.X-50,n.Y+25))
    dp.Nodes.Add(Node(n.X-25,n.Y+50))
    dp.Nodes.Add(Node(n.X+25,n.Y+50))
    dp.Nodes.Add(Node(n.X+50,n.Y+25))
    dp.Nodes.Add(Node(n.X,n.Y-40))

    DrawingList.AddElement(dp)

  DrawingList.EndCommand()

DrawingList.RequestData(diamond, DrawingList.RequestType.PointType)
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Not sure of the etiquette here. I went home a built a stand-alone example. I then added a blog entry (http://oldschooldotnet.blogspot.com/2011/04/scripting-ccli-with-ironpython-visual.html) about it - plus a link to tha zip file containing the entire VS2008 project.  I am placing a link at the top of the post, but would/should I have re-written the answer now that I have a better example?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need .NET functionality, you could rely on embedding Python instead of IronPython. See Python's documentation on [Embedding Python in Another Application](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) for more info and an example. If you don't mind being dependent on [BOOST](http://www.boost.org/), you could try out its [Python integration library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/index.html).